# Adding string Elements in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I have mutable string  array named arrayout.
It is having 3 element .Now I want to add 1 String element that array.But when I try to add,it is taking null value....Cant get what to do...Please help...

My code is :

```
       NSString *ds1 = @"--";
        [arrayout arrayByAddingObject:ds1];
        NSLog(@"arrrrr '%@'",arrayout);
```

Comment: As written in the documentation; arrayByAddingObject creates a *NEW* array instead of appending to arrayout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
NSString *ds1 = @"--";
[arrayout addObject:ds1];
NSLog(@"arrrrr '%@'",arrayout);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it this way:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayout = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];        // alloc here
[arrayout insertObject:@"SomeText Here" atIndex:[arrayout count]];  // insert here
NSLog(@"Appended Array: '%@'",arrayout);                      // Print here
```

this will populate `arrayout` with `SomeText Here`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you concatenating strings like this ?  You can just do something simple like

```
NSString* newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", string1, string2, string3];
```